# Why can't I debug each line of Gradle build script?

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, groovy, remote-debugging

When remote debugging a gradle build using the typical command line args (`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`) I am only able to stop on breakpoints within classes I have provided; I am not able to stop within the build script itself.

This is obviously an expected behavior, according to various sources, including [here](https://georgik.rocks/how-to-debug-gradle-script).  For example:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'  // not able to stop debugger here

class Penguin() {
    def ork() {
        println 'ork!'  // able to stop debugger here
    }
}

new Penguin().ork()
```

I'm trying to understand why is this?  Why does Gradle not allow debugging of every line in the build script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it's very similar to groovy, the `build.gradle` file is a custom DSL that is parsed by Gradle. Breakpoints can only be added to `.java` or `.groovy` files and there is no such file to add your breakpoints to.

I believe that if you were to use the [kotlin-dsl](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl) instead of the `groovy DSL` you might be able to put breakpoints in the kotlin buildscript and debug in IntelliJ IDEA but I'm not 100% sure on this

If you really wanted to debug you could move everything to a plugin which can be debugged and have a single line in `build.gradle`

$root/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: MyBuildScript
```

$root/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/MyBuildScript.groovy

```
import org.gradle.api.*
class MyBuildScript implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.with {
            apply plugin: 'foo'
            dependencies { ... }
            task bar(type: Baz) { ... }
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```